# Which error codes can the "NAME ... AS ..." function throw?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, fileserver

**Scenario**: Multiple PCs running Excel VBA code want to have write access to one Excel file on a server, but only one is allowed win, so I need an `isWinner()` function.

**Code Idea**: Every PC trys to rename the same specific txt-file using `NAME ... AS ...` as this should be an atomic operation in a multi user environment. The PC, that does not get an error, wins. Errors then can be handled using `Err.Number`. When the PC is done with it's write operation on some 'protected' file, it restores the original name of the specific txt-file, so the next pc can have a go. (something similar to [this tutorial](https://solveandexcel.ca/2020/08/25/prevent-two-users-from-editing-the-same-file-with-excel-vba/), but stripped down to the core idea of synchronised access)

---

**Question**: Which errors can the `NAME ... AS ...` function throw?

I found a list of [*common* errors](https://chejunkie.com/knowledge-base/common-runtime-error-codes-vba/) and "[58 - File already exists](https://vbaf1.com/functions/name/)" seems to be one of them, but I can't find any good documentation on this excel vba function which would list these.

---

Side-questions, that I would appreciate some input on, but they are more like a 'note-to-myself'.

- Is there more than one scenario where the function returns an error code of 0 / runs error-free?
- What exactly happens step by step when `NAME ... AS ...` is called?

Comment: Have you considered alternative options, like a database? So rather than trying to solve this problem, it might be better to have a solution that doesn't have the problem.

Comment: Or just handle an error thrown when you try to open the excel file for the update.

Comment: You got the right idea there, and I've given it a lot of thought, but in this case I want it to be based on an easy-to-handle file on a fileserver. Nothing else but Excel and Windows needed. Furthermore am I just curious about the inner workings of this perticular Excel VBA function.